# memory increase a lot everytime I swipe to the next page. Instrument leak reports and static analyzer is OK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-leaks, instruments

use ARC in xocde. The app's material page is like this:
[image]

The app runs well but when I swipe to the next page, the memory increase a lot (mostly 30k per page) as instrument allocation gives the following:
[image]

The detail is :
[image]

I don't understand what's going wrong? My env is : xcode 4.5.2, ARC enabled. Really appreciated someone can help me.

The heapshot is:
[image]

Then the heapshot detail :

[image]

I'm very sure that I removed all the view objects when swipe to the next page so the app should clean the memory of those view objects in the previous page. Just don't know why these 304 bytes of objects increase the memory and what is wrong here .

Comment: The first image is particularly useful in an English language community...

Comment: Looks like `FT_Outline_Decompose` in _libCGFreetype_ is leaking `CGPath`'s...

Comment: neilsbot, how can I locate where exactly the leaking is? I certainly have no such CGPath code in the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is seemingly a case of abandoned memory. Abandoned memory is not exactly leaking memory, in that you are not losing track of that memory. Rather it is memory that is not deallocated when it could/should be, so that overall memory usage increases.

Have a look at [this article](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/instruments_help-memory-allocations-help/Finding_Abandoned_Memory/07_Finding_Abandoned_Memory.html) for a way of dealing with this using heapshot analysis in Instruments.

Another interesting, step-by-step discussion of the heapshot analysis method is [here](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/03/08/using-heapshots-to-find-abandoned-memory.html).

Comment: Thanks sergio. Here I got the img by heapshots:

Comment: from the heapshot, I see that the issue has not to do with views or other Objective-C objects; rather it seems some lower-level Core Graphics stuff. Could you explain (in your question) what do you do to display each page? Are you using come framework? Are you doing Core Graphics? Does the "detail view" in Instruments gives you some hints as to where that memory is allocated?

Comment: when the user swipe left, the app goes to the next page reading dataset from database. Here is the simple logic：1, remove all views in the current page. 2, read dataset. 3, loop the dataset (15 records each page), add UILabel as subview into the current page.

Comment: Try to comment-out pieces of that code to find out where the abandoned memory is allocated. I.e., don't read a new dataset (of course the page content won't change, but that is ok) and see if the memory problem is still there; if not, you have found what memory you are not freeing; otherwise, try with another hypothesis.

Comment: this is interesting, when I swipe to the new page, the memory increase .But if I swipe back to the previous page, the memory remains the same. I believe the app cached the view objects and not release them in time. In my case, this is unacceptable cause there're too many pages of different type of data.